# How to get parameters on client side passsed by HTTP GET request?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, callback

I need to catch a callback in my razor view page from some social service API.
The callback request is implemented by HTTP GET method:

```
http://www.contactsimporter.com/home.cshtml
```

After callback is implemented I need to retrieve parameters (param1=value1&param2=value2) from HTTP GET request.
For example:

```
http://www.contactsimporter.com/home.cshtml?param1=value1&param2=value2
```

I need to retrieve this parameters param1=value1&param2=value2 from callback URL.

How can I get those parameters using JavaScript or jQuery code?

Comment: What do you mean "catch a callback?"

Comment: 'some social service api' call for your application action with parameters? why you want ta parse query string from view? why not from action method?

Comment: I think you need to read query string params, have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Adapted from [CSS-Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/get-url-and-url-parts-in-javascript/)

- To access to the url: `window.location.pathname`

Now you can treat the url like a normal string in Javascript and parse it accordingly.

```
var url = window.location.pathname
var getQuery = url.split('?')[1]
var params = getQuery.split('&') 
// params is ['param1=value', 'param2=value2']
```

Comment: but were those rows have to be?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand your comment. Do you mean *where those rows have to be? Can you define rows?

Answer (score 9):

You can achieve it by pure javascript. Refer below code to do so :

```
var urlParams = window.location.search
var getQuery = urlParams.split('?')[1]
var params = getQuery.split('&')
```

Comment: this is probably the better solution, as window.location.search only gets the query string

Answer (score 1):

You can also use URLSearchParams

```js
const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
const entries = urlParams.entries();
// build params object
const params = {};
for (entry of entries) {
  params[entry[0]] = entry[1];
}
console.log(params);
```

Answer (score 1):

Avoid using `window.location.pathname`
It only return the path
You also need the query string parameters, so instead pathname, use href as follow

```js
var url = window.location.href
var getQuery = url.split('?')[1]
var params = getQuery.split('&') 
// params is ['param1=value', 'param2=value2']
```