# Open a accordion FAQ content with outside link

Tags: javascript, accordion

I have an issue with trying to open a specific block of content from our home page to the specific question the user would click.  I would like it to automatically open the question they click on our home page that opens up to the FAQ page.  I have tried using anchors and it just moves it down to the specific question but doesn't show the content.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
    <!-- Begin Accordion Snippet -->
<style>
  .so-tab {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 25px 0;
  }
  .so-tab label {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    padding: 0 25px 0 0;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    line-height: normal;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  .so-tab input {
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: -1;
  }
  .so-tab-content {
    max-height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: max-height .35s;
  }
  /* :checked */
  .so-tab input:checked ~ .so-tab-content {
    max-height: none;
  }
  /* Icon */
  .so-tab label::after {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    display: block;
    -webkit-transition: all .35s;
    -o-transition: all .35s;
    transition: all .35s;
  }
  .so-tab input[type=checkbox] + label::after {
    content: "+";
  }
  .so-tab input[type=radio] + label::after {
    content: "\25BC";
  }
  .so-tab input[type=checkbox]:checked + label::after {
    transform: rotate(315deg);
  }
  .so-tab input[type=radio]:checked + label::after {
    transform: rotateX(180deg);
  }
</style>

<h2>Section 1 FAQs</h2>
<div class="so-accordion-wrapper">
  <div class="so-tab">
    <input id="so-tab-1" type="checkbox" name="tabs">
    <label for="so-tab-1">What is the best trail camera that sends pictures to your phone?</label>
    <div class="so-tab-content">
     <a name="q1"> <p>The Browning Defender Pro Scout cameras are our number one-rated cellular trail camera at the moment. You can choose between the Browning Pro Scout AT&amp;T Cellular Trail Camera, or the Browning Pro Scout Verizon Cellular Game Trail Camera. These cellular game trail cameras take excellent photos and get great battery life.</p></a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="so-tab">
    <input id="so-tab-2" type="checkbox" name="tabs">
    <label for="so-tab-2">What is the the best motion activated trail camera?</label>
    <div class="so-tab-content">
      <p><a name="q2">The Browning Patriot Trail Camera has our top-rated score at this time. This trail game camera takes excellent photos, videos, and gets great battery life. If you are looking for the best motion activated trail camera purchase it with Trailcampro today.</a></p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="so-tab">
    <input id="so-tab-3" type="checkbox" name="tabs">
    <label for="so-tab-3">Are wireless trail cameras worth it?</label>
    <div class="so-tab-content">
      <p><a name="q3">Wireless trail cameras give you the ability to receive photos or videos directly to your phone. Getting real time photos of deer and other wildlife to your phone is invaluable. You can also use wireless trail cameras for security applications.</a></p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="so-tab">
    <input id="so-tab-4" type="checkbox" name="tabs">
    <label for="so-tab-4">What is the best cellular trail camera for the money?</label>
    <div class="so-tab-content">
      <p><a name="q4">The best cellular trail camera for the money is the Browning Pro Scout Verizon or the Browning Pro Scour AT&amp;T cellular trail game camera. These cellular cameras are $199.95 and take great photos, get great battery life, and are easy to use.</a></p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="so-tab">
    <input id="so-tab-5" type="checkbox" name="tabs">
    <label for="so-tab-5">What is the difference between a game camera and a trail camera?</label>
    <div class="so-tab-content">
      <p><a name="q5">Wildlife cameras are called by a few different names. Some users call them game cameras, trail cameras, scouting cameras, and wildlife cameras. There is really no difference between a game camera and a trail camera. There are many different models of both and they can be called both a game camera, or a trail camera. Read our trail camera and game camera reviews here at Trailcampro to find the best game or trail camera to fit your needs.</a></p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="so-tab">
    <input id="so-tab-6" type="checkbox" name="tabs">
    <label for="so-tab-6">How high off the ground should a trail camera be?</label>
    <div class="so-tab-content">
      <p><a name="q6">There are many different scenarios for setting up trail cameras. There is not one particular way that it has to be done. However, as a rule of thumb we recommend mounting trail cameras about waist high. This usually works for most settings like placing a game camera on a trail, or maybe watching a feeder.</a></p>
      
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="so-tab">
    <input id="so-tab-7" type="checkbox" name="tabs">
    <label for="so-tab-7">What is the best trail camera for home security?</label>
    <div class="so-tab-content">
      <p><a name="q7">There are many different trail cameras you can use for security. Some of them will have the ability to send photos to your phone using a cellular connection through Verizon or AT&amp;T. On of our top picks for a cellular security camera is going to be the Ridgetec Lookout. If you are looking for a cellular trail camera for home security one of our top-picks is going to be the here. If you don't have a cellular signal where you are wanting to place the security trail camera. The Reconyx Hyperfire 2 Security may be a good option for you.</a></p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="so-tab">
    <input id="so-tab-8" type="checkbox" name="tabs">
    <label for="so-tab-8">How much does a cellular trail camera plan cost?</label>
    <div class="so-tab-content">
      <p><a name="q8">When choosing a cellular trail camera the cost of the plans can be important. Spypoint seems to offer the best monthly and yearly plans especially if you are wanting an unlimited plan. Most cameras are going to start around $10 a month and that is going to get you a set number of photos per month or a specific amount of data per month. To check out all the cellular cameras and their plans click here and choose which cellular game camera you want to look at.</a></p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="so-tab">
    <input id="so-tab-9" type="checkbox" name="tabs">
    <label for="so-tab-9">How do I view my trail camera pictures on my phone?</label>
    <div class="so-tab-content">
      <p><a name="q9">Almost everyone has a smart phone these days and you can use them to view your trail camera photos. Typically when you have a iPhone the best thing to purchase is going to be an iPhone SD card reader. You would want to purchase one made by Apple as we have seen issues with other brands. If you have an Android device you could use the Stealth Cam 4-IN-1 reader. It seems to work well with Android phones but has issues with iPhones.</a></p>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are okay with using JavaScript for this, you can make use of `<HTMLElement>.click()`.

If you have a query parameter passed whenever you click on the FAQ bit (such as `?faqclick=specificquestion`), you can use `.click()`. If you need information on getting the query parameter from the client side, use this post: [How to get parameters on client side passsed by HTTP GET request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26565381/how-to-get-parameters-on-client-side-passsed-by-http-get-request)

An example of `.click()` would be `document.querySelector("#myUniqueQuestion").click()`

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  I am not very well versed in JS...actually most of this I am not well versed in:)  I have checked the link and I am still not following anything there.  I did have a script working on a different layout but I cannot seem to adapt it to this new layout.

Comment: Can you link the code that you have written?