# How to access the parameters in the client-side javascript send through res.direct(url) in the server (express)

Tags: javascript

On the client-side, I am redirecting using the syntax as `window.location.href=url` and reaching `server-side(express)` after performing few actions, from there again redirecting with a URL (`res.redirect(url)`).

Here, both the URLs are the same but along with the URL sent from the server-side am passing few parameters. So, how to fetch those parameters on the client-side (javascript).

Comment: You mean query string? like "example.com/path?foo=bar&baz=qux"

Comment: Just to be sure that I understood the question; query string can be used to write data on the url. Using that you can read the URL and do whatever you want with the data. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string

Comment: I think he means https://stackoverflow.com/a/26565508/1235106

Comment: (Just FYI, with different query strings, these URLs are _not_ the same.)

Comment: @kevin, I tried to fetch it using window.location.search but it didn't work. Initially as I redirected from the client, I don't know how to get the response

Comment: For eg: If we send using window.location.href= "aurl.com/link=anotherurl.com" from client-side (passing the link parameter to server so that later point I need to append that link ) and perform few action in server-side and from there redirecting using res.redirect("anotherurl.com&params="+parameters). Now how to access the parameters in "anotherurl.com" in client-side javascript

Comment: @barbarbar338, query string only but how to get it for the redirected response

Comment: i guess you are looking for this one https://stackoverflow.com/a/901144/10124281